# Which layer7 protocol used the YouTube streaming

Tags: firewall, youtube, pfsense, network-protocols

I want to restrict the bandwidth on YouTube in pfsense firewall. I try to setup layer7 with set the limit on http video/audio,flash, swf protocol and created the separate rule for YouTube but did not work. Please let me know which streaming protocol used on YouTube?

Comment: [Does YouTube stream Videos via TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19620219)

Comment: Via TCP as well as UDP and any port used for same?

Comment: Read all the answers

Comment: @Devid I Read all comment, then how to restrict bandwidth on pfsense firewall?

Comment: YouTube already limits its own bandwidth usage. If you do this, your videos will freeze, or suffer a loss of quality.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I need to restrict bandwidth in my own network because any one open the youtube with HD video, at that time freeze the whole network :)\

Comment: out of interest, what device are you using to run pfsense?

Answer (score 1):

First of you are kind of doing "reverse engineering":

You are trying to understand how YouTube works and then "adapt" it to your needs.

IF you will get that to work it could for a short period of time. Services like YouTube are actively changed to improve it.

On the other hand the method that YouTube uses to function will most likely be used by many other programs (so blocking them too!).

What you could do (not sure if that is possible in pfsense) is use the hostname [youtube.com] (or even use an IP range) to restrict that in amount of data used or speed or whatever.

Comment: As above, I did that but not work and also did the setup layer7 protocol and applying on rule that is also not work. So that I want know protocol or Port number.